# is it possible to try catch an assert call in a static library(c++)

Tags: c++, try-catch, assert, rapidjson

Is it possible to try catch an assert call in c++?
Im using the library rapidjson(static library) and its annoying because if it fails to find something in a json file it calls assert. When i want to avoid it calling assert and do the error handling myself.

Comment: Asserts shouldn't be used in the case of a "normal" failure. They should only be used when some illegal state has been reached and there isn't any sensible form of recovery that's possible. Perhaps you're misusing rapidjson? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333371/when-to-use-assert-and-when-to-use-try-catch?rq=1

Comment: You might want to validate your json with a schema first.

Comment: Ok thanks ill look further in how my code is designed

Comment: To @GameHog and everybody else who is frustrated with rapidjson assertions: according to the Author of rapidjson - there is no easy way to replace assert() with a different mechanism. To avoid assertion in rapidjson you have to test/validate the pointer (or key) in your JSON object every possible way before calling a function on it, which means you have to write a lot of extra code.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot catch an assertion since they have nothing to do with exceptions. The function/macro `assert(expr)` is part of C and will cause program termination in an implementation defined manner if the supplied expression evaluates to `false`. More detail can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).

If you have access to the source of the library in question, recompiling it with the preprocessor macro `NDEBUG` defined should disable all assertions. Do note though that this will not replace the assertion with an exception: `assert()` will just be replaced by a no operation, no matter to what the supplied expression evaluates.

If you desire exceptions (or any other kind of *effective* error handling) instead, you will have to modify the library to suit your needs.

Additionally, there is always the possibility of using another library that adheres to modern C++ design practices. For example, [this one](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) is suited well if your toolchain supports modern C++.